# Sketch the general shape of the graph of $f$. $f'=\sec^2 x, -\pi/2<x<\pi/2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Sketch the general shape of the graph of $f$.

> $$f'=\sec^2 x, \hspace{25 pt}-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

To find critical points.

$\sec^2 x=0\Rightarrow \sec x=0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos x}=0\Rightarrow \frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos x}=0\Rightarrow\sin x\cdot \tan x+\cos x=0$

$\sin x \cdot \tan x=-\cos x=\cos x\Rightarrow\sin^2 x=\cos ^2 x\Rightarrow\cos ^2x-\sin ^2 x=0\Rightarrow\cos 2x=0 $

$2x=\cos^{-1}(0)\Rightarrow 2x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow x=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$

but as per the solution book there are no local extrema, from the graph of $\sec x$, I know that it is never zero, but what highschool algebra mistake I am doing in the above mentioned steps that I don't know, so pls tell what is wrong above?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cos x} = 0$ That right there can't happen. The trig manipulations after that point only introduce additional roots which don't satisfy the original equation.

Comment: oh ok, i get it, thanx, so the argument is that since 1/cos(x)=0 is not possible, so there are no critical points.

Comment: There are no local extrema, and since $\cos x \ne 0$ on the given interval there are no critical points.

Comment: The "high school algebra mistake" which you are committing is $\cos x = -\cos x$. If you correct this step, you will end up with $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =0 \implies 1=0$ (which is not possible). @dxiv - I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre You are right, and my first comment could/should have dropped the last sentence, which was due to a misread. What I said was basically that any search for extrema should have stopped right at $\frac{1}{\cos x} = 0$, since that was an equation which obviously had no solutions.